# What Wire/Switch Combination to use for Garbage Disposal Outlet

Tags: electrical

I have a garbage disposal that is plugged into a 15A outlet on a 20A GFCI protected circuit. The circuit is wired with 12 gauge wire. For the switch I would like to install to control the 15A outlet for the garbage disposal I have 2 questions:

1. Should the switch be 15A or 20A?
2. Which wire (12 or 14) should be used to run between the outlet and the switch?

Answer (score 2):

If the breaker is 20A, the wire and switch must be 20A rated. So 12 AWG wire. 20A switch.

"15A outlets" are a special case, and are all rated for being used on 20A protected circuits.